# iPhone, How do I rotate an UIImageView around a point using Core Animation and CATransform3D?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, transform

This is what I want to do:

```
(1) (2) 
|    /
|   /
|  /
| /
|/
*
(3)
```

I want to move an UIImageView represented by a clock pin (width:9px, height 73px) from position (1) to position (2) around point (3) which is one end of the image. 
I tried to set the anchorpoint to (0,0) or to set the image center to point (517,177) which is the *(3) location on the iPad screen, but I had no success:

My degreeToRadians macro is defined in the following way:

```
#define degreesToRadian(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0)
```

/*
     kmPointer is the UIImageView
     */

```
NSValue *value = nil;
CABasicAnimation *animation = nil; 
CATransform3D transform;
kmPointer.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[kmPointer.layer removeAllAnimations]; 
animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"]; 
transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(30), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
value = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]; 
[animation setToValue:value]; 
transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
value = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]; 
[animation setFromValue:value]; 
[animation setAutoreverses:NO]; 
[animation setDuration:1.0f]; 
[animation setRepeatCount:1]; 
[kmPointer.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

How can I make the pointer to rotate around the star marked with (3)?

Comment: Are you sure the anchor point is (0,0)? I think that's the top left, not the bottom left.

Comment: I read all this things http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html
I tried all the combinations, (0.5, 0.0), (.0, .5), (1, 0), (1, 1) and I still don't obtain the desired effect.  

When I put the anchorpoint (1,1) my pointer goes up on the screen by 50 pixels and rotates to right around the new (3) point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Apple docs that show the anchor point image are for OSX. Here is what it looks like for iOS:
[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100728-8ggje4xr8jixa7c2gam96npc9g.png](http://img.skitch.com/20100728-8ggje4xr8jixa7c2gam96npc9g.png)

So try setting your anchor point to 0.0, 1.0.

Comment: it works partially, because the rotation is done right but before the animation is started the image moves to another place on the screen. I think that I have to set some boundaries.  
Anyway I went with another approach, because the image was rotating correct around the center, I maximized the image such that the center is the pin bottom.