# Rotating a control on its rightmost bottom point

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4

Hi I want to rotate a control on its right bottom point(like a clock needle). I am able to do so with the following code :

```
self.label.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
self.label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

But the problem here is that my label shifts a bit on the x axis to left and then rotate. I am not getting what's wrong.. Please help.

Similar post: [iPhone, How do I rotate an UIImageView around a point using Core Animation and CATransform3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350315/iphone-how-do-i-rotate-an-uiimageview-around-a-point-using-core-animation-and-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do in this situation is move the label over prior to the animation block. For instance, if you are changing your anchor point to CGPoint 1.0,1.0 then simply apply a transform to that label prior to the animation. You can save a reference point in your viewDidLoad to the original location also if you plan on performing multiple transforms. *Code hasn't actually been compiled but this should give you a good idea.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    // CGPoint originalLabelsOrigin is declared as a property
    originalLabelsOrigin = self.label.frame.origin;
}  

self.label.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);
self.label.layer.frame = CGRectMake(originalLabelsOrigin.x + self.label.frame.size.width, originalLabelsOrigin.y + self.label.frame.size.height, self.label.frame.size.width, self.label.frame.size.height);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
self.label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Hey thanks! it worked but with a slight change in suggested code changing second line to :                           self.label.layer.frame = CGRectMake(originalLabelsOrigin.x, originalLabelsOrigin.y, self.label.frame.size.width, self.label.frame.size.height);

Comment: The general idea is to move the view over the same amount as you move the anchor point (where the object will rotate from, view.frame.size.width/2 & view.frame.size.height/2 would be dead center). What you can also do is setup a multiplier using the CGPoint values. For example, create a variable for the x and y and multiply those values by the view's corresponding frame sizes then use that value. That way it will move over the exact amount every time. If the answer worked for you, please mark the solution as the answer with a comment so I can begin racking up some points here. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

So finally what i asked can be achieved by following code as suggested by Captain :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
// CGPoint originalLabelsOrigin is declared as a property
originalLabelsOrigin = self.label.frame.origin;
}  

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
self.label.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0, 1.0);
self.label.layer.frame = CGRectMake(originalLabelsOrigin.x, originalLabelsOrigin.y,         self.label.frame.size.width, self.label.frame.size.height);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
self.label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
[UIView commitAnimations]; 
}
```

Still not too sure with the reason but it works.